# Can I have two embedded ActiveMQ queues in JBoss?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, activemq-classic

I have set up ActiveMQ as an embedded broker (from this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/ironjacamar/configuring-a-resource-adapter-for-activemq-on-jbosswildfly)), and now I want to add a new application, in a different EAR, which needs a new queue.

Has anyone been able to do this?

If I try making two resource adapters in my standalone.xml, they end up using the same broker-config, and I get the error below.  So that doesn't seem right.

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [broker-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=brokerOne
```